# Updating any cell from a formula in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

Say I have the formula: `V = IR`

In Excel, I need to calculate any of the combinations of this possible.

For example,

- if I am given the value of I and R, I would need to display the result of V in the cell in which I have V (user keeps it 0 or blank to denote that's the value he wants to find out)

Excel sheet before:

```
+------+---------+------+
| V    |   I     |   R  |
+------+---------+------+
| 0    |   1     |   10 |
+------+---------+------+
```

Excel sheet after:

```
+------+---------+------+
| V    |   I     |   R  |
+------+---------+------+
| 10   |   1     |   10 |
+------+---------+------+
```

- if I am given the value of V and R, I would need to display the result of I in the cell in which I have I (user keeps it 0 or blank to denote that's the value he wants to find out)

Excel sheet before:

```
+------+---------+------+
| V    |   I     |   R  |
+------+---------+------+
| 10   |   0     |   10 |
+------+---------+------+
```

Excel sheet after:

```
+------+---------+------+
| V    |   I     |   R  |
+------+---------+------+
| 10   |   1     |   10 |
+------+---------+------+
```

Coding a function to check if a cell is 0 and updating another "answer" cell (besides V, I, R; this cell calls this function explicitly) with the expected value is no issue.

The challenge is in having the blank cell (value that we need to calculate from the other variables provided) update besides the extra "answer" cell.

**Excel does not allow a formula to update any cell**, and this will require some workaround - which I cannot think of.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint about how to work this out... :^) Rather than trying to enter a formula in the cells, write a VBA script that figures out which of the three permutations of your formula to apply given V = IR, based on which cell is empty. So your first part of your logic will look something like this:

```
if cellV == "" and cellI <> "" and cellR <> "" then
   cellV = cellI * cellR 
elseif cellV <> "" and cell I = "" and cellR <> "" then
   cellI = cellV/cellR 
elseif cellV <> "" and cell I<> "" and cellR = "" then
   cellR = cellV/cellR
else
   alert("must provide at least two out of three values before evaluation");
```

and attach this to whatever event you like. for instance an event that checks if 2 out of 3 values have been specified (like onUpdate or something)

Please know that this is just pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Excel-only solution as far as I know. You'll have to use VBA.

This worked for me:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Electricity()
    Dim nEmptyCells As Integer

    nEmptyCells = -CInt(IsEmpty(Range("Voltage"))) _
        - CInt(IsEmpty(Range("Current"))) _
        - CInt(IsEmpty(Range("Resistance")))

    If nEmptyCells = 1 Then
        If IsEmpty(Range("Voltage")) Then
            'Calculate voltage
            Range("Voltage") = Range("Current") * Range("Resistance")
        ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("Current")) Then
            'Calculate current
            Range("Current") = Range("Voltage") / Range("Resistance")
        ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("Resistance")) Then
            'Calculate resistance
            Range("Resistance") = Range("Voltage") / Range("Current")
        End If
        Range("Notification") = "Calculation successful."
    ElseIf nEmptyCells > 1 Then
        Range("Notification") = "Insufficient input."
    ElseIf nEmptyCells < 1 Then
        Range("Notification") = "Too much input. Problem is overspecified."
    End If

End Sub
```

Note that I gave names to the cells corresponding to V, R, and I, as well as to a "Notification" cell that will give useful feedback to the user. If you don't want to give them names, then you can just used e.g. `"B2"` instead of `Voltage"` etc. Also I only checked for blank cells and not for zero values. I'll leave that part to you.

The above macro belongs in a code module, and has to be run manually. You could place a CommandButton on the sheet and make it run the macro when clicked by the user. Alternatively, if you want it to run automatically every time the user changes the inputs, you can place this in the sheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("Voltage").Address _
        Or Target.Address = Range("Current").Address _
        Or Target.Address = Range("Resistance").Address Then

        Electricity

    End If
End Sub
```

This is what I thought of off the cuff. With a bit more work you can make it nicer and more user-friendly.